# HTML with Ionic3, how to seperate rows

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this HTML where I need to seperate each row, how can I do this?

This is what I have:

[image]

```
<ion-grid class="grid-16 box">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let device of connectedDevices" align-items-center>
        <button ion-item ion-col col-12 (click)="selectDevice(device)">
            <ion-col col-auto><img [src]="getIcon(device.physAddress)" height="28"></ion-col>
            <ion-col>{{ getName(device.physAddress, device.hostName) }}</ion-col>
            <ion-col col-auto>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col class="grid connection">
                        <img *ngIf="device.interfaceType == 'Wifi'" src="assets/icon/ico_device_wifi.svg" width="21">
                        <img *ngIf="device.interfaceType == 'Ethernet'" src="assets/icon/ico_device_lan.svg" width="21">
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col class="grid success">{{ liveboxWifiDevicesCms.literalConnected }}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-col>
        </button>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

This is what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that you have used `box` I guess it is the box with shadow. Use this class on `ion-row` instead of `ion-grid` . Along with that use some `margin-bottom` in ion-row

Comment: I didnt notice I had a class in there !! Arghh, thanks!